# What is the purpose of handshakelocal in multichain?

Tags: blockchain

What is the use of **handshakelocal** api command when i have cluster of nodes. When to use it ? what are the benefits and why ?

Answer (score 1):

**handshakelocal** Manually override the wallet address which is used for handshaking with other peers in a MultiChain blockchain. This is helpful if the address previously used for handshaking has lost connect permissions, and the node does not yet know which of its other addresses to use, because it has been disconnected from the chain.